# Why is my mesh disconnecting from my armature?

Tags: mesh, armature

I have a simple human rig set up that used to work perfectly fine but now things seem to not work correctly.

In this case, my forearm mesh disconnects from my armature even though the entire bone has been weight painted.

What could be causing this?

[image: mesh being disconnected]

[image: weightpainting]

Comment: Maybe it's accidentally partially weighted to another bone too.

Comment: as Scurest says, this part must be part of another vertex group as well, so maybe select this part in Edit mode, go into the Vertex Groups list, on the dropdown menu on its right choose Remove From All Groups, then weight paint with the right bone selected